# How to load a resource when folder of resources have the same name in the main app and in the library?

Tags: java

In the main app in the resource folder I have a folder named "sci". An app uses a library (as jar as dependency) which also has a folder with the same name in resources.

When I calling `getClass().getResource()` i got a location of resource located in the jar

```
/Documents/project/ru-s/app/libs/my-library.jar!/sci
```

How to load a resource from main app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ClassLoader.getResources()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources(java.lang.String)) to find all resources of a given name, when they exist in multiple jar files.

So instead of `Something.class.getResource("foo")` you use `Something.class.getClassLoader().getResources("foo")` to get an `Enumerator` over all resources of that name on your classpath.